# jquery select menu and deselect other menu

Tags: jquery, html

Hi I have two dropdown menus: priceMaximum and mortgageMaximum

I want it so if a user selects priceMaximum then the 'No Maximum' value is displayed in the mortgageMaximum dropmenu and vica versa.

I have done it with the following code but it seems to only work in Firefox, so Safari, IE9, and Opera it doesn't work, can anyone suggest an alternative?

```
$('#priceMaximum option:not(:first-child)').click(
    function()
    {
        $('#mortgageMaximum option:not(:first-child)').hide();
    }
);

$('#priceMaximum option:first-child').click(
    function()
    {
        $('#mortgageMaximum option').show();
    }
);

$('#mortgageMaximum option:not(:first-child)').click
(
    function()
    {
        $('#priceMaximum option:not(:first-child)').hide();
    }
);

$('#mortgageMaximum option:first-child').click
(
    function()
    {
        $('#priceMaximum option').show();
    }
);
```

My html is as follows:

```
<select name="priceMaximum" id="priceMaximum" class="thin">
    <option value="999999999" selected="selected">No Maximum</option>
    <option value="200000">200.000</option>
    <option value="400000">400.000</option>
    <option value="800000">800.000</option>
    <option value="1200000">1.200.000</option>
    <option value="2400000">2.400.000</option>
    <option value="5000000">5.000.000</option>
    <option value="10000000">10.000.000</option>
</select>

<select name="mortgageMaximum" id="mortgageMaximum" class="thin">
    <option value="999999999" selected="selected">No Maximum</option>
    <option value="300">300</option>
    <option value="500">500</option>
    <option value="750">750</option>
    <option value="1000">1000</option>
    <option value="2000">2000</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this can help you:

```
$('#priceMaximum').change(function(){

   if($(this).val()!='999999999'){
     $('#mortgageMaximum').val('999999999');
   }

});
```

and viceversa for the other menu

```
$('#mortgageMaximum').change(function(){

   if($(this).val()!='999999999'){
     $('#priceMaximum').val('999999999');
   }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar issues with `select` boxes before, and the trick is to change the event from `click` to `change`

```
$('#priceMaximum').change(function () { /* do something here */ });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    // put all that stuff here

});
```

http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 0):

Trying to disable / hide the options is not supported well by browsers.

You'll be better off removing the options and adding them back in when needed.

Use `.remove()` and `.append()`